# OSM route inside campsite

Tags: mapbox, routing, mapbox-gl-js

I have a problem that I want router to route only inside campsite if starting point is inside campsite, not around campsite as the example in the image. Is there any way to do it? If it is important, I am using Mapbox directions.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the routing engine setting ? if yes you probably have to allow routing on private road (or on the kind of road that are inside the campsite) by default it probably only use road that are open to public circulation

Comment: The problem is not in road type. All road types you see on the map are the same type. Check this image, if I just move a little bit end point (B), then it goes through the campsite. https://imgur.com/gallery/h1xMmok Probably my problem is that OSM/Mapbox calculates route by nearest road to ending point. I am trying to find a way to make him calculate the rout inside polygon/campsite (if I can describe it like that).

Comment: If you can control the cost associated to each road segment, you can put a very high cost on the segments being the campground gate(s): routing will be cheaper all-within or all-outside the campground, while still allowing crossing the gate if routing can't be done otherwise.

Comment: JGH thank you for the idea, seems good, ill try that!